# Appending a Dynamically Built Element to Another Dynamically Built Element

Tags: jquery, append

I have a jquery ui framework that is constructing the Date Picker elements.  I also have jqtransform dynamically altering the input field.  Bottom line I need to take the dynamically created `<img>` and append it to a parent div, three divs deep.  To help visualize this I created a JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/helpinspireme/PnJvn/  The goal is to append the `<img>`tag right above the `<input>` field within the `<div>` element.

I am also wrapping the  tag in a `<div>` once all is said and done.  I just need help appending the `<img>` tag to the correct place.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
//get the input
var input_div = $('.date_picker')
//get the image
var img = $('img.ui-datepicker-trigger');
//wrap the input and add the img before it
input_div.wrap('<div class="datepicker_image" />')
        .before(img);
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/uvVd8/

Comment: Beautiful.  Thank you very much for you assistance.  I'll mark this as the answer once stackoverflow allows me.

Comment: This answer is wrong, `wrap` method returns the original set of elements and not wrapped element. Check your markup after executing this code.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli if you look at the fiddle there is a div that wraps both the img and the input field, i figured that he wanted it that way! :)

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti is correct.  I wanted the `wrap()` to work the way he presented it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether I understood your question correctly but here is what you can try. Find the `input` element and then use `before` method to add the image element right above it.

```
$('.date_picker').wrap('<div class="datepicker_image" />')
$('.datepicker_image').before($('.ui-datepicker-trigger'));​
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/PnJvn/4/

Comment: This doesn't wrap the input and the image in another div

Comment: OP mentioned wraping is not important so I didn't care about it. Anyways edited my answer.